# how to show textview and edittextview on same line?

Tags: android

this is my code for show edit text view and text view on separate line how i show both on a same line please help me can anyone tell me how is possible???
  how i show  label  Login   and edittextview  at a same line???

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>          

    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dip"
      android:layout_below="@id/header">
      <!-- Full Name Label -->


      <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"

    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

           <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="160dip"
        android:text="Send /Load Money"
        android:textColor="#FFCC00" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
        android:text="___________________ "
        android:textColor="#99CC00" />


           <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dip"
        android:text="Pay Individual"
        android:textColor="#FFCC00" />






          </LinearLayout>





        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/lblTPIOtherAccount"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFCC00"
            android:text=""/>         


      <EditText  android:id="@+id/txtTPIotheraccount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"

            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"

            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>
      <!--  Pin Label -->
      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/lblTPIPinno"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFCC00"
            android:text=""/>
      <EditText 

         android:id="@+id/txtTPIpinno"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"

            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>




      <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/lblTPIAmount"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFCC00"
            android:text=""/>



      <EditText android:id="@+id/txtTPIamount"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>

      <!-- Register Button -->      
      <Button android:id="@+id/btnTPIsubmit"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Submit"/>

         <Button   android:id="@+id/clearTPIButton"
             style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Clear"/>
          <Button android:id="@+id/btnTPIgoback"
              style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Go Back"/>


    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Registration Form Ends -->
```

Comment: put both of them in a linear layout whose orientation is horizontal

Answer (score 1):

write below XML code into your main layout code, it will solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTxtView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mEdttxt1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Enter Name" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `TextView` and `EditText` into `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` attribute